# 'void' type not allowed here, Callable func

Tags: java, sorting, higher-order-functions, callable

I'm trying to get a function be a parameter to a function through Callable. As you try to run it, it would say the error **'void' type not allowed here** at **long a = timer(sort.Insertion(A));**

Why is that?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ThisClass {
    public static Sort sort = new Sort();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("location/here.txt"));

        int z = 0;

        while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            z++;
        }

        int[] A = new int[z];
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            A[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print(" " + A[i]);
    }

        long a = timer(sort.Insertion(A));
    }

    public long timer (Callable func) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        func.call();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return end - start;
    }

    public static void print (int[] A) {
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + A[i]);
        } 
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sort {

    public void Insertion (int[] A) {
        for(int j = 1; j < A.length; j++) {
            int key = A[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while((i >= 0) && (A[i] > key)) {
                A[i + 1] = A[i];
                i = i - 1;  
            }
            A[i + 1] = key;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. And if anybody could just help with other ways of having Higher Ordered Functions in Java, or having functions being passed as paramaters in functions, that would be great. And very well appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Sort` class?

Comment: I suspect that `sort.Insertion(A)` does not return a `Callable` object

Comment: try to look again @alfasin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that `Sort.Insertion()` has `void` return type.

If you are trying to call it on a timer, you need to wrap it in a `Callable`, like so (untested):

```
    long a = timer(new Callable<Void>() {
        Void call() {
           sort.Insertion(A);
           return null;
        }
    });
```

This will require `A` to be made `final`. Change `Void` as appropriate.

Comment: Suppose Insertion Sort is an Array of Integers, what should I put in 'Void'?